# How to implement North and South sections in same JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

Is it possible to have a north and south component in the same `JPanel`? For example, I want text to display with a 2 x 2 grid layout below. How could I change this code to make that happen? I'm new to Java Swing and am not sure where I should look.

```
public  CompView(){
super("Super");
setResizable(false);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);

JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();

getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
northPanel.add(new JLabel("TITLE", CENTER));
northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
northPanel.add(new JLabel("Text: "));
northPanel.add(new JTextField());
northPanel.add(new JLabel("Text: "));
northPanel.add(new JTextField());

getContentPane().add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
middlePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
middlePanel.add(new JLabel("Title 2:", CENTER));
middlePanel.add(new JTextField());
}
```

Current Image

[image]

I would like the output to look like this:

```
| Super             |_|  |X|
----------------------------     --|
|          Title           |       |
----------------------------       |
| Text: | JTextField 1   | |       } North Panel
----------------------------       |
| Text: | JTextField 2   | |       |
----------------------------     --|
|         Title 2          |       |
----------------------------       } Center Panel
| | Resizable JTextField | |       |
----------------------------     --|
```

Hope this diagram helps.

Comment: *"Is it possible to have a north and south component in the same JPanel?"* Yeah, sure. Just add a panel to each of the north and south, then set a new layout for each as appropriate. General tip: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: BTW - `getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
 ..  getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` A component (e.g. `northPanel`) can only appear in one place. Should the second one be `southPanel`?

Comment: If you make the second component a different panel as @AndrewThompson suggested, then this code should work as far as I can see.

Comment: @john01dav I plan to have three panels. This is only for the first. I know I can have more than three panels, however, I am unsure how to correctly format them. I tried earlier however some components were above others where they should not be.

Comment: @ConfusedStudent It is unclear exactly what you are asking. Can you edit the question to include your full code, a screenshot of what it produces, and a drawing of what you want it to look like? This will allow us to see exactly where your code differs from what you want.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I plan to have other panels, however whenever I have multiple, the layout messes up and things go above others.

Comment: So .. where is that ASCII art or drawing I suggested you post? You'll likely remain a confused student unless you listen very carefully to my suggestions and implement the advice offered.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Took a while, but I have changed the post. Hope it helps

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

A common strategy to solve complex computing tasks, is to break them into small, well defined manageable tasks. Divide and conquer. 
This also applies to gui: break the design into small, easy to layout containers. In this case start by dividing the design into 2 areas, as you did (north and south), and subdivide each. For example:

[image]

The basic ideas is to divide the layout into smaller areas, each having simple distinct layout that can be implemented by one [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

An implementation of the north part could look like:

```
//avoid extends JFrame. Use for simplification
public class CompView extends JFrame{

    CompView(){

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,0));

        FlowLayout layout1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(layout1);
        titlePanel.add(new JLabel("TITLE"));
        northPanel.add(titlePanel);

        FlowLayout layout2 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        JPanel textfieldPanel1 = new JPanel(layout2);
        textfieldPanel1.add(new JLabel("Text: "));
        JTextField txt = new JTextField();
        txt.setColumns(5);
        textfieldPanel1.add(txt);
        northPanel.add(textfieldPanel1);

        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new CompView());
    }
}
```